# MINFLTs for an already paged-in buffer?

Tags: linux, performance, memory-management, kernel, virtual-memory

Ubuntu server 16.04 OOTB install. 
A server with 12 cores doing nothing, and 144GB RAM

I have this simple c app that does:

```
A=malloc(1024*1024*1);
memset(A,0,1MB);
B=malloc(1024*1024*1);
memset(B,0,1MB);
C=malloc(1024*1024*1);
memset(C,0,1MB);
```

I then have an infinite loop that on each iteration calls

```
memcpy(c,a / b,1MB);
```

(Each iteration I switch the source between A and B);

And when i check MINFLT for this process it keeps rising. 
While i would expect that for 3MB on such machine, the first memsets will “fault-in” (page-in) everything, making these buffers resident and thats it.

Anyone knows why this happens?
It happens on 8k allocations as well so its not a size issue
The mahine is otherwise idle.

Thanks in advace!

Comment: @tsyvarev i don’t see why this is not a kernel question... ?

Comment: As far as I understand, the question is about the *user space* utility `ps -o MINFLT` and a *user space* program. While observed behavior may be affected by the Linux kernel implementation (well, almost everything is affected by the OS kernel), the question is not about programming inside Linux kernel. And tag [tag:linux-kernel] implies exactly Linux kernel programming.

Comment: I wasn’t aware of that. So I’ve added kernel.

Comment: No, the tag [tag:kernel] has similar [usage](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/kernel/info): "This tag is for general questions regarding code that runs in the context of an operating system kernel". Please, read a tag's info before adding the tag to the question.

Comment: Ok. But this is not about ps ps only shows stuff exposed by the kernel.  The question is why would that behavior cause faults.